# Python: Rank array by other array

Tags: python

I have two arrays arr1 and arr2 that have the same elements but sorted in different ways:

```
arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
arr2 = np.array(['c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'])
```

What I would like to do is get a third array in which each element is the position that each element in arr1 occupies in arr2.

In the example above the desired output would be:

```
arr3 = [1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```

since the element 'a' occupies the position 1, the element 'b' occupies the position 3 and so on

Comment: I suggest you step away from the computer and think about the steps you would take to do this by hand. If I wrote these two lists of letters, what would you do to create the third list if you had to do it without a computer. Write down these steps in words on a piece of paper before trying to write code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `np.where` to get your desired result:

```
arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
arr2 = np.array(['c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'])

arr3 = [np.where(arr2 == x)[0][0] for x in arr1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ndarray

arr1: ndarray = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
arr2: ndarray = np.array(['c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'])

def array_find(arr1,arr2):
    arr3=[]
    for x in arr1:
        for i,val in enumerate(arr2):
            if x==val:
                arr3.append(i)
                break

    return arr3
arr3=array_find(arr1,arr2)
print(arr3)
```

Output

```
[1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did here is convert the numpy array to a list and use the index() to find the position of each element:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
arr2 = np.array(['c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'])

arr3 = []

for elm in np.ndarray.tolist(arr1):
    arr3.append(np.ndarray.tolist(arr2).index(elm))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the most efficient way, but it works.

```
>>> np.array([np.where(arr2 == v)[0][0] for v in arr1])
array([1, 3, 0, 4, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Via list comprehension:

```
arr3 = np.array([i for value1 in arr1 for i, value2 in enumerate(arr2) if value1 == value2])
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be a simple for-loop:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(list('abcde'))
arr2 = np.array(['c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'])
arr3 = []

for letter in arr1:
    arr3.append(int(np.where(arr2 == letter)[0]))

print(arr3)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```